# Is there a way to force after effects to import custom File Types through a .jsx Script?

Tags: javascript, scripting, jsx, extendscript, after-effects

Let's say i gave a custom file type for my AE project:

I changed it from **character.aep** to **character.czip**

i can easily import this file through AE's GUI ( **File -> Import -> All Files Type -> character.czip** )

I'd like to write a script that does the same, so i wrote:

```
var main_path = (String(new File($.fileName).parent));
var io = new ImportOptions(File (main_path+"/character.czip"));
var myFootage = app.project.importFile(io);
```

But this script keeps preventing me from importing the file, it gives the error:

**After Effects error: FIle "character.czip" is not a valid file type for import.**

Is there a way to bypass the file format check, as we do on ae's GUI?
Or at least, force the after effects to interpret the .czip file as .aep?

Comment: Doesn't look like you can. The ImportOptions object seems to check the imported file to see what kind of file it is, and obviously it just looks at the extension. Can you get your script to change the name of the file while it imports it, optionally changing it back at the end?